# How to select text using CodeMirror2 code in UIWebview IOS 5

Tags: javascript, ios5, uiwebview, contenteditable, codemirror

I tried to used CodeMirror 2 for making a text editor in UIWebview IOS 5. But i had  problem in text selection. I couldn't select text.

This is codemirror code in codemirror.js,

```
// Wraps and hides input textarea:
'<div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; ' + 
             'width: 3px; height: 0px;">' + 
    '<textarea style="position: absolute; padding: 0; ' +
                     'width: 1px;" wrap="off" autocorrect="off" ' +
                     'autocapitalize="off">' + 
    '</textarea>' +
'</div>' +
```

from that code, I think i have to use "div" with contenteditable properties. 
I plan to change textarea become "div" with contenteditable property becouse for now, iOS 5 has support contenteditable property. But, i'm not sure how to do that. Any one know how to solve my problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

CodeMirror was build in a way to avoid using contentEditable, because is not implemented the same across browsers.

This is a demo of a custom build of CodeMirror2 that works on iOS (I am not the author): http://www.litech.org/~schanzer/iOS/

If you're interested in the changes that were made to make it work try searching for "iOS" or "CHANGE" in the source, or use it as it is.

Here the [updated source](http://www.litech.org/~schanzer/iOS/lib/codemirror.js)

Comment: Appreciate for this work but it's a very huge and buggy solution.